# See when my skill reprompts users

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there a way to see if my skill has reprompted a user? I know this happens if a user doesn't respond within an allotted amount of time and it would be informative because I'd like to rephrase some of my responses if this tends to happen more frequently for some utterances than others.

Answer (score 1):

No. At this point, this isn't possible. You might be able to use a timer in your skill service to guesstimate however.